# Rsync: Combining '--files-from' and '--exclude' does not work

Tags: rsync

I do my backups with `rsync` and used the option `--files-from` to define a list of directories that should be synced. Right now, I am planning to extend the command by the `--exclude` option, but it does not work.

More specifically, the `include-list.txt` file already contains the directory `/home/user/shared/` and I want to exclude the new subdirectory `/home/user/shared/BIG_DATA/`.

Here is the command that does not do the job.

```
rsync -azvvr \
    --files-from '/home/user/BACKUP_MNGMT/include-list.txt' \
    --exclude '/home/user/BACKUP_MNGMT/exclude-list.txt' \
    -e ssh / user@server:/home/user/Backup
```

Answer (score 3):

You can combine `--files-from` and `--exclude` but it's not quite as straightforward as one might think. (TL;DR? Jump to the end.)

Consider a simple example. Here is the set-up

```
mkdir -p dst src/a src/b/c
n=1
for d in $(find src -type d)
do
    ps -ef > "$d"/file$n.txt
    n=$((n+1))
done
```

The result is this directory tree, which we'll use for our examples:

```
src/file1.txt
src/a/file2.txt
src/b/file3.txt
src/b/c/file4.txt
```

Using `rsync` in the trivial case we get everything, as expected:

```
rsync -av --dry-run src/ dst/
file1.txt
a/
a/file2.txt
b/
b/file3.txt
b/c/
b/c/file4.txt
```

Using `rsync --exclude b` you can see that we exclude `b` successfully. What's actually happening here is that because `b` is no longer considered, none of the files underneath `b` are found or copied:

```
rsync -av --dry-run --exclude b/ src/ dst/
file1.txt
a/
a/file2.txt
```

The problem is that when you provide a list of files that includes entries under `b`, the exclusion of `b` itself is applied but the files underneath it do not match the `--exclude b` clause and are therefore included:

```
find src | rsync -av --dry-run --files-from=- --exclude b/ . dst/
src/
src/file1.txt
src/a/
src/a/file2.txt
src/b/
src/b/file3.txt
src/b/c/
src/b/c/file4.txt
```

The solution is to specify in the `--exclude` clause that not only `b` but also all its descendants are to be excluded:

```
find src | rsync -av --dry-run --files-from=- --exclude b/ --exclude 'b/**' . dst/
src/
src/file1.txt
src/a/
src/a/file2.txt
```

---

In your case, you also have a number of other issues with your command. Here are a couple of variants that may work, depending on what is actually in the files lists:

```
rsync -azvv --no-r \
    --include-from '/home/user/BACKUP_MNGMT/include-list.txt' \
    --exclude-from '/home/user/BACKUP_MNGMT/exclude-list.txt' \
    -e ssh / user@server:/home/user/Backup

rsync -azvv \
    --files-from '/home/user/BACKUP_MNGMT/include-list.txt' \
    --exclude '/home/user/shared/BIG_DATA/**' \
    -e ssh / user@server:/home/user/Backup
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but anyway :)

```
--exclude=BIG_DATA/
```

Should do the trick in this case.
Don't forget the trailing slash....

Comment: 5 months != old.  I'd venture to guess that 2+ years is the threshold for old

Comment: Moreover, it doesn't matter if the question is old, if the answer is helpful ;)

Comment: Does not work on my tests! As explained by Chris Davies, You need specify in the --exclude clause that not only BIG_DATA/ but also all its descendants are to be excluded (BIG_DATA/**) because of the --files-from

Answer (score 0):

there are some things to consider:

- first you have to decide to use `--exclude=` (specify the rule within the command) or `--exclude-from=` (read a file with exclude-rules).
- decide what should be excluded... maybe everything with the name `BIG_DATA`, all folders with the name `BIG_DATA/` or just explicitly the folder `/home/user/shared/BIG_DATA/` within the sync-folder.
- files/folders/rules starting with `/` are usually starting in the source-root NOT system-root.
  without a starting `/` they can be everywhere.
- the last rules which is applicable to a file/folder wins.

so your command with `--exclude=` (and excluding just this one folder) could be something like

```
rsync -azvvr --files-from='/home/user/BACKUP_MNGMT/include-list.txt' --exclude='/home/user/shared/BIG_DATA/' -e ssh / user@server:/home/user/Backup
```

or for `--exclude-from=`

```
rsync -azvvr --files-from='/home/user/BACKUP_MNGMT/include-list.txt' --exclude-from='/home/user/BACKUP_MNGMT/exclude-list.txt' -e ssh / user@server:/home/user/Backup
```